# Admob Interstitial Ad showing fine but not clicking

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I am facing a problem regarding Admob **Interstitial Ad.**
The Interstitial ad shows fine and works absolutely perfect as required.
But when user clicks on it, nothing happens.

I know there are couple of solutions on the forum i.e.

but my problem is a bit different with a slightly different code.

**Here is my snippet from manifest:**

```
 <!-- ADS -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

---

**MainActivity.java:**

```
   /**
     * Show an interstitial ad
     */
    private void showInterstitial(){
        //if (fromPager) return;
        if (getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id).length() == 0) return;

        if (interstitialCount == (Config.INTERSTITIAL_NAVIGATION_INTERVAL - 1)) {
            final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id));
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            });
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);

            interstitialCount = 0;
        } else {
            interstitialCount++;
        }

    }
}
```